# Is it possible to use coffee file system (as a library) in my project without the Contiki OS?

Tags: contiki

So, for an embedded project with external `NOR` flash and existing commercial `RTOS`.

Can I use the coffee filesystem in a form of a library, i.e. to compile it in? From what I've seen it seems possible, only the dependencies go quite deep in to `Contiki`. I'll surely dig in, but may be someone have done something of the kind already?

Comment: Eventually in this case I've created a pseudo-fs specifically for this case, since I only had to have read-only access from my main application and full write only from a bootloader. This is more effective than an actual fs for a small embedded project if nothing more is required.

Answer (score 2):

This does look very doable.

From a quick grep in [`core/cfs/`](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/core/cfs) it looks like there are no Contiki-specific abstractions used in the implementation of CFS. And another very quick search on [GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=coffee_page_t&ref=searchresults&type=Code) shows that [swift-nav/piksi_firmware](http://swift-nav.com/) [contains](https://github.com/swift-nav/piksi_firmware/tree/a9ab327c12faeffc52c3d47c6998d1ce5c4a9977/src/cfs) and [uses](https://github.com/swift-nav/piksi_firmware/blob/79f0ba3c4bb6389dcd7444fe6f982a8f17624095/src/position.c) CFS without Contiki.

Comment: Looks you're good in quick searches ;) Going to investigate this direction, thanks a lot!